# Can't fill_in value because Capybara don't see popup

Tags: ruby, automation, popup, capybara

As I know, when popup/modal opens it is on the top of page where I opened it from, so when try to fill value in it don't see where it need to do that.

Then tried to look inside modal with **within**. Tried other classes, but same **Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible css "modal183"**

```
within('modal183') do
        fill_in 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbId', :with => '10'
      end
```

Tried also find with xpath, but also nothing
**Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible xpath "//input[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbId']"**

```
<div class="modal183">
            <div class="popup_Titlebar" id="PopupHeader">
                <div class="TitlebarLeft">
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblTitle">text</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup_Body">

                <div class="popup_TextNoTop">
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl1" class="label-left">text</span>
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbId" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbId" class="txtInputDec width100" onFocus="ClearTheTextbox(this, &#39;&#39;)" onBlur="FillTheTextbox(this, &#39;&#39;)" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers()" />
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cmrvIB" style="color:Red;display:none;"><a href='#' class='tooltipCons'><img src='/App_Themes/Default/img/exclamation.png' alt='' /><span>text</span></a></span>
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_revIB" style="color:Red;display:none;"><a href='#' class='tooltipCons'><img src='/App_Themes/Default/img/exclamation.png' alt='' /><span>text
</span></a></span>
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rvTb" style="color:Red;display:none;"><a href='#' class='tooltipCons'><img src='/App_Themes/Default/img/exclamation.png' alt='' /><span>text</span></a></span>
                    <br />
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbl2" class="label-left">text</span>
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tb1Id" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tb1Id" class="txtInputDec width100 top5" onFocus="ClearTheTextbox(this, &#39;&#39;)" onBlur="FillTheTextbox(this, &#39;&#39;)" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers()" />
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rev1IB" style="color:Red;display:none;"><a href='#' class='tooltipCons'><img src='/App_Themes/Default/img/exclamation.png' alt='' /><span>text
</span></a></span>
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rvTb1" style="color:Red;display:none;"><a href='#' class='tooltipCons'><img src='/App_Themes/Default/img/exclamation.png' alt='' /><span>text</span></a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup_Buttons">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            <a onclick="if (!window.event) {this.disabled=true; this.style.color=&#39;grey&#39;; var but = document.getElementById(&#39;btnCancel&#39;); but.disabled=true; but.style.color=&#39;grey&#39;;};" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnOkay" class="cool-button width80 blue" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnOkay&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;cons&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">text</a>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnCancel" class="cool-button width80 black" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnCancel&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Atcelt</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

***Updated:*** Attached part where it looks like be this popup which appear after I press on button. Inspect code shows on this code. I didn't wrote this code, but trying to build automated tests on them :)

```
<div id="popupparent" style="display: block; height: 1e+06px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


    function resizeIframe(obj) {
        var h = "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
        var w = "innerWidth" in window ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.offsetWidth;

        var doc;
        if (obj.contentDocument) {
            doc = obj.contentDocument;
        } else if (obj.contentWindow) {
            doc = obj.contentWindow.document;
        } else {
            return;
        }

        var childHeight = doc.body.scrollHeight;
        var childWidth = doc.body.scrollWidth;


        obj.style.height = childHeight + 'px';
        var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();
        var parent = document.getElementById('termsofuse');

        if (ver > -1) {
            parent.style.marginTop = ((h - childHeight) / 2) - 64 + 'px';
        } else {
            parent.style.top = ((h - childHeight) / 2) - 64 + 'px';
        }

        parent.style.left = ((w - childWidth) / 2) + 'px';
        parent.style.display = "block";
        parent.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
```

```
<div id="termsofuse" style="left: 1081px; top: 246.5px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
<iframe id="frameeditexpanse" frameborder="0" src="PopDailyCons.aspx?e=c0lEPUMwMDEwMDA3MDQmYUlEPUEwMDQ3ODIxNzAmZGF5PTImY3VyRGF0ZT0yMDE4LjA0JmN1clVzZXI9MTYwJnNvdXJjZT1hdGs=" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" class="termsOfUseFrame" style="height: 185px;"> </iframe>
<div class="popup_Buttons" style="display: none">
            <input id="btnOk" value="Done" type="button">
            <input id="btnCancel" value="Cancel" type="button" onclick="hideusertermwindow()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `within` call doesn't work because you need to pass it a CSS selector.  You're passing `modal183` which would look for a `<modal183>` element, when what you really want is `.modal183` to look for an element with the class `modal183`.

From your description it's tough to tell exactly what you're doing but it sounds like maybe you're talking about a popup window (new browser window) opened on top of the current tab.  If that is the case then you'd need to swap windows in order to interact with it, along the lines of

```
new_win = window_opened_by do
  # whatever action in the original window causes the popup window to open
  click_button 'blah' 
end

within_window(new_win) do
  fill_in 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbId', :with => '10'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answerm but got tihs error "Capybara::WindowError: block passed to #window_opened_by opened 0 windows instead of 1". Found information that need to increase Capybara.default_wait_time, but after that still got this error

Comment: @MārisL ok, that would imply it’s not a popup window, you’ll need to update your question to clarify exactly what you’re doing

Comment: in my case that popup isn't new browser window, but like modal which open in front of page. Background is like parent and then that modal/popup is like child. Don't know how to explain in other way. Something like this --> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp press on "Open Modal"

Comment: Attached part of code with that popup at the end of first question. Maybe that can help somehow